# python 'str' object has no attribute 'items'

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, dictionary

i was trying to loop on txt files which contain dictionary
 my code is reading it as  string also tried changing those txt file to json but as those words are in single quotes so it say:

Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes

code

```
for jfile in file_txt.glob('*.txt')            
      with jfile.open('r') as ifile:
          lines_dict=ifile.read()
          for page, word in lines_dict.items():
                    lines = convert_text_to_lines(word)
```

error

```
    for page, word in lines_dict.items():
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'items'
```

example of my txt file

```
{1: [((86, 27, 168, 50), 'haha'), ((85, 53, 195, 63), ' work for you.'), ((323, 49, 408, 57),       'Total  due'), ((534, 42, 590, 59), '4.10'), ((323, 66, 515, 77), ' do not need to make')}
```

Comment: What the file contains is a string representation of a dict - not an actual dict. It's a bit like looking at the picture of a book - you can't flip its pages but you can use the picture to find the real book. In your case you must first convert the file contents back to an actual dict, e.g. via `ast.literal_eval`.

Comment: Is that the actual content of your file? Are you sure there isn't, say, a closing `]` missing near the end?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case `lines_dict` is of type `str` and not `dict`,that why you cannot unpack it .So use `literal_eval` method from `ast` module.

Signature solution is posted

```
import glob
import ast
for jfile in glob.glob('*.txt'):
      print(jfile)
      with open(jfile,'r') as ifile:
          lines_dict=ast.literal_eval(ifile.read())
          for page, word in lines_dict.items():
                    lines = convert_text_to_lines(word)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `read()` returns a string, and a string doesn't have any attribute 'items' unlike dictionaries. The other answer which suggested using `readlines()` is incorrect as well because that would just return a list.
(Edit : looks like the answer got deleted, but nevertheless).

Two things:

1. I assume you copied your text data incorrectly, there was a ] bracket missing at the end.

<s>2) `json.load()` would have been a great solution to the problem had your data used double quotes instead of single quotes.</s> Turns out even had the data had double quotes, the integer keys and tuples would be a problem like MisterMiyagi pointed out in the comments.

Anyway one work around is to use `ast.literal_eval()` (which is a bit safer than raw eval)

```
for jfile in file_txt.glob('*.txt'):        
    with jfile.open('r') as ifile:   
        lines_dict=ast.literal_eval(ifile.read())
```

For eval vs ast.literal_val, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15197673/using-pythons-eval-vs-ast-literal-eval)

Comment: Please avoid suggesting that Python notation is "almost" JSON. People will get the wrong impression and try to convert one to the other. There are far more differences than whether "had your data used double quotes instead of single quotes". Even just in the example shown, JSON would choke on the integer keys and tuples.